# Is there a way to create a chart with only a single axis?

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to create a "chart" where I only want to show the x-axis. Basically I'm trying to create visualization of a range (min-max) and a point that sits in between like:

[image]

I'm unable to find any resources online on how to make this, or what this type of plot is even called. If anyone could help out, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward to achieve through styling a [`line`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html) chart appropriately and using [`linear`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html) x- & y-axes with points defined via [`x` and `y` coordinates](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#point).

By keeping `y` at `0` you can assure the points all appear in the same horizontal position.

The example below gets the visual result you want, but you'll probably want to disable tooltips for the 'fake' x-axis line via a [callback](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html):

```js
let range = {
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  },
  pointVal = 65;

new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ["", "", ""],
    datasets: [{
      pointBackgroundColor: "green",
      pointRadius: 10,
      pointHoverRadius: 10,
      pointStyle: "rectRot",
      data: [{
        x: pointVal,
        y: 0
      }]
    }, {
      // this dataset becomes the 'fake' x-axis line.
      pointBackgroundColor: "black",
      borderColor: "black",
      data: [{
          x: range.min,
          y: 0
        },
        {
          x: range.max / 2,
          y: 0
        },
        {
          x: range.max,
          y: 0
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    hover: {
      mode: "point"
    },

    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 10,
        right: 10,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "linear",
        display: false
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: false
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:200px">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: @DannyYang Did this answer your question?